# Laravel-Vuejs App not running in live domain

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am getting no error but a couple of warnings: I am sharing the image of the application landing page, It's a completely blank page, while it runs nicely in localhost:

[image]

Codes from router.js

```
import { createRouter , createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import store from './store'

import website from './app/layout/website.vue'


import home from './app/website/frontpage.vue'
import hospitals from './app/website/hospitals.vue'


import notfound from './app/website/not_found.vue'

const routes = [
    {
        path : '/',
        name : 'home',
        component : home,
        meta : { layout: website, visitor : true, requiresAuth : true}
    },
    {
        path : '/hospitals',
        name : 'hospitals',
        component : hospitals,
        meta : { layout: website, visitor : true, requiresAuth : true }
    },

    {
        path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
        name: 'notfound',
        component: notfound,
        meta: {layout: website, visitor : true}
    }
]

var router = createRouter({
    history : createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})

function loggedIn() {
    return store.state.authenticated
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if(!loggedIn()) {
            next({name : "login"})
        }else{
            next()
        }
    }else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.visitor)) {
        if(loggedIn()) {
            next({ name : "dashboard"})
        }else{
            next()
        }
    }else{
       next()
    }
})

export default router
```

It was working while I uploaded without any CRUD system, just routes,app,store etc and html.

Comment: console log your redirect rules and check to see if you are getting what is expected. It's clearly stating there is an infinte loop which is sending the request back and forth between / and /login

Comment: I already have deleted navigation guard and router.push , still getting the same error, is that cach ?

Comment: could be,try clearing cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit this code to be like this

```
if(!loggedIn() && to.name!="login") { next({name : "login"}) }
else{ next() }
```

The problem is the router is redirect user even in the login page and that make infinite loop